# page not able to get data from database in IE 8 on click of anchor tag

Tags: internet-explorer, caching, zend-framework2, browser-cache

I have an PHP application with Cart functionality. On the header menu I have a icon called Cart with display of number of items in cart (example : Cart-10). When I click on cart-10 which will redirect to View cart page (cart-10 is an anchor tag with specific URL in ZF2). Upon clicking on it, no data getting displayed on the cart page even though having some cart items added to the cart. The same functionality works fine in other browsers. 
Currently I've placed the below code, which is working okey in IE 11 (but still fails at some point)

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

Comment: We can't really help just by showing html headers. Can you give more details ? (views, controller, exception in log, whatever that can be more talkative than html tags...)

Comment: The problem got resolved. I'm adding     <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" /> at the bottom of the page too.